# PHP definir caminho de um arquivo

Tags: php

eu queria saber como eu faço para obter um caminho através de um DEFINE.

Exemplo:

Eu quero coloca o caminho do meu css mas eu quero tornar isso dinâmico sem ter que fica colocando "../caminho/style.css".

eu quero tipo BASEPATH . '/caminho/style.css'

Bom espero ter sido claro. Sou um pouco leigo em php.

Comment: Não entendi, se você quer definir seu próprio base path, pode fazer com, por exemplo, `$base = "http://exemplo.com/caminho"; require "$base/style.css";`

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam show! e isso ai mesmo que eu queria. E que eu pesquisei e eu estava fazendo com __FILE__ e __DIR__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com $GLOBALS talvez resolveria seu problema.

> $GLOBALS is a PHP super global variable which is used to access global variables from anywhere in the PHP script (also from within functions or methods).

Ficaria algo assim:

```
$GLOBALS['BASEDIR'] = '/seus/assets';
```

E no seu front:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo $GLOBALS["BASEDIR"];?>/css/qualquer.css'/>
```

Em todos seus assets, você usa a mesma expressão para o base dir:

```
<?php echo $GLOBALS["BASEDIR"];?>
```

Dai, se por acaso sua estrutura de pastas mudar, você só precisa mudar a GLOBALS basedir.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou bastante @Andrew Ribeiro. Era exatamente isso que eu queria. Funcionou 100% aqui.

Comment: @Pablo̶F̶r̶o̶z̶ coloque a resposta do Andrew como CERTA. Apenas você tem o poder para fazer isso.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode organizar seu projeto melhor, assim não precisa usar uma superglobal.

Por exemplo coloque dentro da pasta public o index.php e também as pastas com seus assets, assim no seu html ficaria assim.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css">
```

Lembrando que é assim que seu servidor vai estar configurado quando colocar seu projeto online, sempre vai existir uma pasta public_html ou www.

As outras pastas com seu código(classes, funções..etc..) sempre coloque um nível antes, como proteção.